# After removing a folder (apache2 I think) I'm having PHP and LAMP trouble

Tags: mysql, php, lamp

When I go to phpmyadmin it says:

```
The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration. <a href="Documentation.html#faqmysql" target="documentation"><img src="themes/dot.gif" title="Documentation" alt="Documentation" class="icon ic_b_help" /></a>
```

I also had wordpress installed it says:

```
Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.
```

So php  mysql extension is not working, but it is installed.

```
root@john:~# sudo apt-get install  php5-mysql
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree    
Reading state information... Done
php5-mysql is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I tried to remove it and re-install it but I had problems:

```
root@john:~# sudo apt-get purge php5-mysql
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree     
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:

  dbconfig-common libdbd-mysql-perl libmcrypt4 mysql-client mysql-client-5.5 mysql-    
client-core-5.5 php5-mcrypt
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:

  php5-mysql*

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 245 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y

(Reading database ... 326631 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing php5-mysql ...
dpkg: error processing php5-mysql (--purge):

 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1

Processing triggers for libapache2-mod-php5 ...

Action 'configtest' failed.

The Apache error log may have more information.

Your apache2 configuration is broken, so we're not restarting it for you.

Errors were encountered while processing:

 php5-mysql

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Note: Everything was working fine till I removed some folder (maybe apache2) then when I tried to install LAMP again I have troubles.

Answer (score 0):

mysqli is included in the php5-mysql package. Run a php script containing `phpinfo()` and check if MySQLi support is enabled.

If it is not, you must edit your PHP configuration. **If it is not present** add the following line to your php.ini file :

```
extension=mysqli.so
```

(restart Apache afterwards)

Comment: thanks  , probleme solved by crating some files the i used to delet :)